# SFDX command in VS Code have improper

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin

I use the `Ctrl+Shift+P` to run a `Create a new Apex class` command. However, I the a pop-up with an error message saying that command `sfdx.force.project.create` was not found. The problem is that somehow the command which is executed by the script replaced colons with full stops. When I run this command from the terminal in its proper form, then a class is created. Is it possible to fix this issue? It is rather a nuisance, but the quick SFDX menu significantly improves development workflow.

Comment: In your VSCode settings, what do you have when you search for `Salesforcedx-vscode-apex › Java: Home`? That setting needs to be set correctly for the Salesforce Extension Pack to work.

Comment: {   "salesforcedx-vscode-apex.java.home": "C:\\Program Files\\AdoptOpenJDK\\jdk-11.0.3.7-hotspot" }

Answer (score 0):

VS Code's commands have a name for every command, such as `sfdx.force.project.create`. This command name is used to look up what module code should be run when the menu item is activated. In other words, `SFDX: Create Project` links to `sfdx.force.project.create`, which calls a script that prompts you for the name to use, and then calls something like `sys('sfdx force:project:create -n $param')`. The command names are cached so they are more or less immediately available on startup, but the Salesforce DX Extension Bundle takes a few seconds to initialize, so some commands may fail for the first few seconds after startup.

First, check to make sure that your extensions are enabled, particularly the Apex extension, which drives most of the commands. Second, check the OUTPUT tab under Apex and make sure that the "language server" has started. If not, you'll need to wait. If you get any errors from the server, you may need to install an appropriate version of Java.

Comment: And what is an appropriate version of java?

Comment: @sfentrydev Try following [these directions](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/find-and-fix-bugs-with-apex-replay-debugger/apex-replay-debugger-set-up-vscode)